# The proper way to create a cron executer script in PHP

Tags: php, cron

I use the script below to execute tasks from the database when visited (via minute cronjob or manual). But I am encountering some problems with it.

```
set_time_limit(56);

$fp = fopen("perform_cronjobs_lock.txt", "r+");

if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB, $blocked)) {
    if ($blocked) {
        echo "Cronjobs is already running!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Couldn't find the 'perform_cronjobs_lock.txt'!";
    }
}
else {
    ftruncate($fp, 0);
    echo "Running the cronjobs!\n";

    $pageid = "perform_cronjobs.php";
    include_once("backend/include.php");

    if(date("i") == "30" OR date("i") == 30){
        // Once a hour jobs
    }

    else{
        //Once-a-minute jobs
        $list = cronjob::select_all_past_cronjob_classes();
        $limit = $cronjob_max_action; // $cronjob_max_action is declared in on of the included files. '10'
        foreach($list as $cronjob){
            if($limit > 0){
                if($cronjob->name != "manual_action"){
                    $cronjob->perform_cronjob(); // The function that does the specified job.
                    if($cronjob->name == "read_rss"){
                        $limit -= 0.1; // Because it's too fast, we can do it like 100 times in a single minute
                    }
                    else{
                        $limit -= 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Function for some database operations that executes as a whole at end of the file
    end_of_file($pageid);

    sleep(2);
    fflush($fp);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN)

}

fclose($fp);
```

I had to use 'flock' to lock the script to prevent running at the same time (it was causing some duplicates). But when it locks the script, it sometimes stuck locked and it was causing latency for actions.

And another problem of this script, it started to give timeout errors (even if i increase the time limit).

What is the proper way to execute specified tasks from database via cronjobs in PHP?
Note: I use an external cron-job site to visit the page, because i thought normal cronjobs are not working properly. Probably both are working right now.

Comment: If you are running a cron every 1 minute, If job 2 gets blocked behind job1 would it not be simpler to just terminate job2. You are only going to have to wait another 59 second for the next one to start

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think so, but my cronjobs are not working properly so I use an external cron job site to execute these. I don't know how to 'terminate' a cronjob. My (probably not working) cronjob is `/usr/local/bin/ea-php74 -q /home/multipost/public_html/perform_cronjobs.php`

Comment: How to terminate a PHP script, its easy `exit;`

Comment: `$fp = fopen("perform_cronjobs_lock.txt", "r+");  if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB, $blocked)) { if ($blocked) { fclose($fp); exit;}`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Where should I put that?

Comment: I just made a suggestion on that

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh okay, I'm going to try it. Thanks for helping!